# First Index of String in Infinite String - Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, sequence, indexof

## Introduction

I have an infinite String. The length of this string is infinite in our imagination and cannot be limited.Suppose that we have a sequence in the String like this:

> "123456789..."

The **points** after the number 9 actually representing the next sequence. So, it will be like this:

> "...7891011121314..."

## Requirements

In this section, I want to explain about the requirement. The requirement is to find the index of first occurrence of input String (called *n*). Let me give you an example:

### Example 1

> n = "3"
>
> First Index of n = 2

### Example 2

> n = "910"
>
> First Index of n = 8

## Problems

I have coded the algorithm to find the index of the String *n*. But the algorithm is only just a while loop to check the index of *n* and add the next sequence number one by one if index of *n* is not found. I **want a better algorithm** for this to find the index of first occurrence of *n* without relying on looping or less looping. At least, the algorithm don't run longer than 2 seconds if the value of *n* is big (Example: 123456790 or 62716855).

#### ---Edit---

Snippet of my Code:

```
while(!num.contains(s)){
    num +=start.toString();
    start = start.add(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

This is my full code: [My Full Code](https://pastebin.com/mR3Xesu2)

Comment: Show the code you already have.

Comment: Nice exercise but ... what have you tried ?

Comment: To say an algorithm runs longer than 2 seconds is meaningless. Depending on the machine used and the quality of the code, the same algorithm can take a very different time to find a solution. What you should be considering here is [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). Please also provide your code so that we can have a look at other potential reasons of slow performance other than the code's complexity.

Comment: I have edit the question and my code and full code. Please look at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a general description of how to solve this problem. Translating it to Java can still be challenging.

Your input String is basically an infinite sequence of all the natural numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ....

I believe the point of the exercise is to identify the first sub-sequence of natural numbers of the input String that the substring `n` belongs to, and then calculate its index without actually constructing the large "infinite" String.

For that purpose, you have to try to split the substring `n` into an incrementing sequence of numbers having as few digits as possible.

First you have to check is the substring `n` creates a sequence of single digits numbers. That is the case, for example, if n == 345678 (note that n may contain both single digit and double digit numbers, for example `n == 345678910`, which you should also be able to identify).

If you fail in that step, you should look for a sequence of double digit numbers. That is the case, for example, if `n == 33343536`. Now, this could get trickier, since `n == 2333435363` is also a sequence of two digit numbers, but the leading and trailing numbers of the sequence (32 and 37) are truncated.

If you fail again, you look for a sequence of 3 digit numbers.

If you don't find any sequence, you treat the entire substring `n` as a single number in the big String.

Now, suppose `n` is `199319941995`, and you discovered in the previous step that the first number in the sequence is `1993`. The remaining work is to calculate the index of the number `1993` in the input String. You know that the single digit numbers take 1*9 indices. The two digit numbers take 2*90 indices. The three digit numbers take 3*900 indices. The 3 digit numbers between 1000 and 1993 take 4*993 indices. Therefore the index of 1993 is 1*9+2*90+3*900+4*993, and that's the first index of the substring `199319941995`.

Comment: so, when the number is random and doesn't form any sequence, have I to find the index by looping?

Comment: @fairyhunter The number is never random. And it always forms a sequence (of one or more numbers). Finding the index is always the same - counting the indices occupied by shorter numbers + the indices occupies by numbers of the same length which are smaller than the number whose index you are looking for.

Comment: Nice explanation, I'm afraid the String n is not always a sequence numbers. The String n can be a random number. The infinite String is always natural sequence numbers though.

Comment: @fairyhunter Yes, I understand the infinite String is a natural sequence of number. This means that `n` is composed of 1 or more numbers of that sequence (though it may contain at most two partial numbers of the sequence - for example `005100` is part of `10051006`).

Comment: That's wright, even random number can be the value of n, like 62716855.

Comment: @fairyhunter 62716855 is a sequence of just one number, so you have to find the index of the number 62716855 within the infinite String (using the same method I described - 1*9 + 2*90 + 3*900 + 4*9000 + 5*90000 + 6+900000 + 7*9000000 + 8 * 52716855 - 1)

Comment: This is working, but you need to edit the index calculation, and you dont need to reduce it by 1.

Comment: @fairyhunter I reduced by one because the first index is 0, but the first number in the infinite String is 1. Perhaps I miscalculated something.Oh, I see were I was wrong now. Thanks.

Comment: @Eran, can you do an example for the number 555899959741198? I do not see any sequence in it but when I run the unsequenced code the answer is much bigger than the actual one.

Answer (score 2):

Using `String` we can do this as follows,

```
String largeValue  = "2323254534534642342354346876985374";
String searchValue = "32545345346423423543468769";
if(largeValue.contains(searchValue)){
    System.out.println("The index is : "+largeValue.indexOf(searchValue));
}
```

Note :-
We can use only `largeValue.indexOf(searchValue)` if it return -1 means that `searchValue` is not present in the `largeValue` Or else you will get the particular index.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering why not simply use `indexOf`, since the String is "infinite", I search if it says anywhere if the method stop at the first occurence (it don't make sense to keep searching...). Note : I would not call `contains` followed by `indexOf`, just store the index returned ;)

Comment: The problem arise if the length of n is up to 15. So, the code will run much longer I'm afraid.

Comment: @fairyhunter The method is looking for the first character, then check the following, if it match, it ends there, if not, it keep search for the first character and so on... The method is quite effective... I don't know on what you are running your code, but iterating a `String` of 15character is really not that long ...

Comment: @AxelH Fixed comment - 15 characters refers to the length of the substring, not the length of the input String, but can be much longer.

Comment: Isn't sequence suppose to be increasing ?  Your string is random, and it's not correct. Also if the says it's infinite, I see it more like a stream of characters, not a string

Comment: @Eran - the length of the search value won't change much if I understand the code of `IndexOf`. It search for the first character before checking the rest of the `String`, one by one. it could be a problem with repetitive sequence probably, to mess with the logic and force it to check long similar block. But in normal usage, it would not be THAT problematic. (I can find a block of 100 character in a random String of 100.000char, the block is a substring near the end, in less than a second)

Comment: The input string is not changing, but the sequence is infinite, so the sequence will continue to increasing non-stop. The problem is that if the input string is random number with large digit length, example 59123975

Comment: @AxelH What if in order to find the first index of 345790367549072 you have to generate a String of 1000000000 characters or 1000000000000 characters? At some point either the search will be very slow, or you will run out of memory. I think the point is to take advantage of the known content of the String in order to calculate the index of the substring without constructing a large input String.

Comment: @Eran I fully agree with that ! But (yeah I like to argue ;) ) since OP tells his `String` has infinite length, using imagination, we can use the same imagination for that solution ;) But clearly, having the algorithm to recognize the pattern of that sequence would be much better (and fun to code)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you could use the `String.indexOf` method:

```
int found = longString.indexOf(searchString);
if(found != -1) System.out.println("Found index is: " + found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside implementing some advanced algorithm like Knuth-Morris-Pratt mentioned in another answer, you could also use finite state machines for string matching. This has the advantage that the backtracking costs are much lower than the naive solution of your while loop but can be easily used with standard javas regular expressions. The solution would be:

```
CharSequence text = // the long sequence of text
String search = // whatever you want to search
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quoute(search)).matcher(text);
matcher.find();
int startIndex = matcher.match();
```

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is : You have a Sequence String like String sequence = "1234567891011121314";
You want to find the index of first occurrence of an input String say ("910") inside this.
If my understanding is correct we have inbuilt function present in Java to do this - sequence.indexOf(input_string) -`String str = "1234567891011121314";
        String sub = "910";
        System.out.println(str.indexOf(sub));`

Answer (score -1):

My idea is to make a statistics about the data, one of the ways is to have all the index locations for each number (0 to 9) and search based on the index data since input text is large and the search speed will be too slow, so the below will lead to very fast search for multiple search inputs on the same large text:

Example using C#: 
(In Java use:

```
HashMap<K, V> and ArrayList<T> and Character.getNumericValue(c)
```

)

```
string input = "................";

Dictionary<int, List<int>> numIndex = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>(10);

for(int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
     numIndex.Add(index , new List<int>(20));

for(int charIndex = 0; charIndex < input.Length; charIndex++){
     for(int index = 0; index < 10; index++){
          int value = Convert.ToInt32(input[charIndex]);
          if(value == index)
                numIndex[value].Add(charIndex);
     }
} 

int FindIndex(string nValue){
    // nValue = "213654789";

    foreach(int indexValue in numIndex[Conver.ToInt32(nValue[0])])
    {
         if(nValue == input.Substring(indexValue, nValue.Length))
              return indexValue; // First Index Value Found
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Edited to add idea for Infinite Buffer, pseudo code logic without buffer close check logic, i left it for user to add it:

```
int charIndex = -1
char charValue 
string textValue = "456321587"
char[] textCompare = new char[textValue.Length]
while charValue = charsBuffer.ReadChar()
BEGIN
     charIndex = charIndex + 1 
     if textValue[0] == charValue 
     BEGIN
          int count = 1
          textCompare[0] = charValue 
          while count < textValue.Length
          BEGIN
              textCompare[count] = charsBuffer.ReadChar()
              count = count + 1
          END
          if textValue == new string(textCompare)
              return charIndex
          charIndex = charIndex + textValue.Length 
     END
END
return -1
```

charsBuffer.ReadChar() may be a large text file buffer or network text buffer or any large text buffer

Comment: Nice code, the problem is still lingering there though. The input is infinite, so the length is not fixed. It's still needing to iterate to get the real index if storing the index to the dictionary.